# Node.js huge performance issue when using static class properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, class, static

I was making some benchmarks on Node.js and I found something interesting: a potential performance issue.

Try running this piece of code with Node (do not try to run it on the browser since it seems there are no problems with javascript on the browser):

```
function benchmark(nrOfTimesToRun, fn) {
    const startTime = +new Date();
    for (let i = 0; i < nrOfTimesToRun; i++) {
        fn();
    }
    return +new Date - startTime;
}

class Property{
    static get(target) {
        return target[this.KEY];
    }
}


class NameProperty extends Property{}
NameProperty.KEY = 'name';
class RoleProperty extends Property{}
RoleProperty.KEY = 'role';

class User {}
var user = new User

NameProperty.get(user);
// RoleProperty.get(user);

const result = benchmark(1e7, () => {
    NameProperty.get(user);
});

console.log('Execution time: %d ms', result);
```

In my case, Node completed the task in `77 ms`. Now uncomment the `RoleProperty.get(user);` line and run the code again.

BOOM. My pc finished the task in `1162 ms`.

What is the problem here? Why it is taking so slow to run the benchmark in the second case?

Debugging this I found that `return target[this.KEY];` might be the problem. More exactly `this.KEY`. **I think Node has a hard time getting the static property.**

Is this a known problem of Node?

Comment: So, the V8 JS engine has several different ways it can optimize property access on an object.  Some of the methods are very, very optimized and very fast.  But, certain things you do  in the code can cause it to have to switch to one of the slower mechanisms.  My guess is that you caused it to go to a slower mechanism for access the `.KEY` property when you did this `RoleProperty.KEY = 'role';`.  I don't know the details enough to know why or if there's a work-around.

Comment: Here are some resources to read: [Fast Properties in V8](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties), [V8 and TurboFan](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/get-ready-a-new-v8-is-coming-node-js-performance-is-changing-46a63d6da4de), [Shapes and Caches](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes) and [Optimizing property access](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shapes-ics)

Comment: I don't know if we V8 is the problem here since the browser has constant results. I was using Node.js 10 to get these numbers but when I switched to Node.js 12 the results came to be on the fast side in both cases. It seems Node.js 10 has sime issues :(

Comment: Well to rule out V8, you would need same version of V8 in both browser and nodejs.

Comment: Correct. I will keep using Node.js 12 from now and remember that Node.js 10 has this problem (with whatever V8 version it has)